# Posting scores for all GameCenter players

Tags: ios, leaderboard

Can you post score in GameCenter for all players at once ? It seems that the API allows only to post for current player. I am trying to implement vote capability allowing current player to vote / score other players in GameCenter.

```
GKScore* gkScore = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:category];

gkScore.value = score;

// ??? Score for current player ONLY - how to record score for other players ???
[gkScore reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(NSError* error) {
     ....

     BOOL success = (error == nil);

     [delegate onScoresSubmitted:success];

 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only post scores for the current player. This is for security purposes.

If multiple people are playing the same game, when they open up their app on their own device, that is when you submit the score.

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 7, this is no longer true. But you can only do so when ending the game, using

```
endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:scores:achievements:completionHandler:
```